# Accessing HTML table data in PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table

I'm generating a table from an SQL Select statement but also adding a check box on each row so that rows can be selected, but I can't work out how to loop through each row of this generated table in order to see if the box is checked.

Is this possible?

I know how to create the table, populate it, and how to check the button, I just can't work out how to access the cell that the button is in on each row.

I can't create each check box individually as they are created along with the table when looping through the rows from my SQL SELECT

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: That does depend on how the data is arranged. Radio buttons are designed so the user can only select one, so you just look for which is selected. If you wanted multiple selections, you could use checkboxes, link them together as an array by adding `[]` to the end of the name and the value as the ID, then foreach through the `$_POST['checkbox_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a **radio** button link the inputs together with an array by adding `[]` after the name. i.e. `<input type="radio" name="foo[]" />`
You can then access the array with a `foreach` loop.

If you want to use a **check**-box give them all the same name also with `[]` in an array, and each a different `value` attribute. i.e. `<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1" />`
You can access the values with a `foreach` loop.

(In both cases you need a default value in an hidden input before each radio button. Otherwise your array is impossible to use as php only reads selected radio buttons.)

Comment: Looks like I have to use a checkbox, I forgot you can only select one radio button.

The issue I have though is the table is just being generated while looping through the rows from my SELECT statement so I can't individually create the checkboxes.

Comment: You could add a counter that adds 1 on each itteration. Or use a value from your SQL row as value.

Comment: That makes sense, I can increment a variable each time it goes on to generate a new row.

I'm not sure how I could use a foreach loop to access the values though?

Comment: Could you post what relevant code you have so far? It is much easier to answer you question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'll admit this isn't the best way to go about this but it'll get your problem solved.

Secondly, I'll suggest you change the HTML Input element to `type="checkbox"`. To be able to know which were checked, you'll need to adjust your code to look something like below:

```
<!-- HTML part -->
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- we need the form as the parent to the table so content can be posted to the server -->
    <table ....>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp</th> <!-- we'll put our checkboxes in this column of the table -->
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkSelect[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /></td>
                ....
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="">Delete</button> <!-- This is assuming we're trying to delete the selected items -->
</form>
<!-- HTML end -->
```

At this point, we have our form ready; note that the checkbox name has the `[]` after it, this allows it to be processed as an array on the PHP side. On the PHP side, you simply need to do your normal form processing like so:

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'btnDelete')) {
    $checkedIds = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'chkSelect', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    // if we loop through the array, we can see the selected item ids
    var_dump($checkedIds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's cleared up some of my questions. I'm a bit unfamiliar with how you do your form processing.
As far as I'm aware filter_has_var is similar to isset?
What is the filter_input doing?

Thanks :)

Comment: @fesil `filter_has_var` checks if there is a variable [really an array key] with that name in the specified superglobal. `filter_input` is the preferred way to access superglobals now as opposed to doing `$checkedIds = $_POST['chkSelect'];`. The other parameters I supplied to `filter_input` was so I could receive the value as an array as opposed to a simple type. You can read more about `filter_input` here -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: I've just got back to this. Okay I get all this, but I'm not sure where I'm going from here.

Once I've looped through the table, I want to add the IDs that are selected to an array, which I can then store in a database.

is $checkedIds an array here?